# My plugin loop jQuery does not work - why?

Tags: loops, plugins

Please help I am making a wp plugin but my jQuery code does not work properly in loop that's why I can't make attribute in this plugin.

Here is the code please help me. Thanks in advance  :)

```
function smooth_ticker_list_shortcode($atts){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'text' => 'Latest News',
        'count' => '2',
        'efect' => 'fade',
        'color' => '#000',
        'speed' => '2500',
        'delay' => '1000',
    ), $atts, 'projects' ) );

    $q = new WP_Query(
        array('posts_per_page' => $count, 'post_type' => 'post')
        );      

    $list = '
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("#smoothticker").inewsticker({
                    speed: '.$speed.',
                    effect: '.$efect.',
                    color: '.$color.',
                    delay_after:'.$delay.',                 
            });
        });     
    </script>
    <div><span>'.$text.'</span><ul id="smoothticker">'; 
        while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
            $idd = get_the_ID();
            $list .= '
                <li>'.get_the_title().'</li>        
                ';        
        endwhile;
        $list.= '</ul></div>';
        wp_reset_query();
        return $list;
}
add_shortcode('smooth_ticker', 'smooth_ticker_list_shortcode');
```